# Scanner readLine() does not read line entirely

Tags: java

I use the following code

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
String[] arr = scan.nextLine().split("\\s+");
System.out.println("n = "+n+" arr length = "+arr.length+" arr last = " +arr[arr.length-1]);
```

to deal with input data of the format

1. the first line contains an integer denoting the number of elements in the dataset
2. the second line contains space-separated integers describing the respective values of dataset

On the input where the first line is "1609" and the second line is cyclic sequence of number from 1 to 20, i. e.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 1 2 3 4 5 ...
```

the output should be

```
n = 1609 arr size = 1609 arr last = 9
```

but it is

```
n = 1609 arr size = 1608 arr last = 8
```

On the dataset which is the same as the previous one but without last number the answer is correct

```
n = 1608 arr size = 1608 arr last = 8
```

What can cause the incorrect behaviour in the fist case?

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball is broken, so can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: *"What can cause the incorrect behaviour in the fist case?"* Last value in the very long line is an `8`, not a `9`.

Comment: The OP is right, it should be `9`, because `1609 mod 20` is `9`. But I've tested it myself, and it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to do here. I suppose what makes this confusing is the fact that, do you expect a User to type in a space delimited string consisting of cyclic values from 1 to 20 into the console a little over 80.4 times to create a string with 1609 values? Okay, let's naturally assume your going to paste the string into the console.

First you need to consider, will the console in your IDE or whatever (in its current state) handle a single string that long? If it has a **Wrap Text** feature (such as there is in NetBeans), perhaps it needs to be turned on before this can be accomplished otherwise the string you paste will simply get truncated to something much shorter therefore providing an incorrect value.

If you are getting an output like as you say: `n = 1609 arr size = 1608 arr last = 8` then I would personally have to assume that there is something wrong with your entry of the **cyclic values string** (heaven forbid if you're actually entering 1609 space delimited values) or there is something wrong with the way you're generating that string which for some unknown reason you're not showing us.

Below is your very same code with some modifications to it so as to demonstrate how this task can be accomplished. I used a **for** loop to generate the **Cyclic Values String** which is also posted within the Console Window for easy copy/pasting into the scanner prompt. Do keep in mind though, you don't need a loop to acquire the desired Cyclic Value. As **@nickkoro** has already so graciously hinted to you, you can use the mod (%) operator to acquire the very same Cyclic Value:  `n % 20 = value` or in other words `1609 % 20 = 9`.

Here is the full runnable code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CyclicValues {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String red = "\u001B[31m";       // Console text Color Red
        String blue = "\u001B[34m";      // Console text Color Blue
        String reset = "\u001B[39;49m";  // Console text Color Reset

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements in current Dataset: ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine().trim());
        System.out.println("\nExample of a space delimited String consisting of cyclic values\n"
                         + "from 1 to 20 which is sized to accomodate the supplied number of\n"
                         + "elements in current Dataset. Make sure you have 'Wrap Text' turned\n"
                         + "on for your Console window if supplying large numbers.\n"
                         + "Hit " + red + "ENTER" + reset + " to continue:");
        // Pause for ENTER Key...
        while(true) { 
            scan.nextLine(); 
            break;
        }

        // Display the Cyclic Values String (cyclic 1 to 20)
        // in Console window...
        int counter  = 1;
        for (int v = 1; v <= n; v++) {
            if(v == n) { System.out.print(red + counter); }
            else { System.out.print(red + counter + " "); }
            counter++;
            if (counter > 20) { counter = 1; }
        }

        System.out.println("\n\n" + reset + "Now copy the generated example string shown above and paste\n"
                         + "it here then hit the " + red + "ENTER" + reset + " Key: --> ");

        String[] arr = scan.nextLine().trim().split("\\s+");
        System.out.println("\n" + blue + "n = " + n + red + " | " + blue + "arr length = " + arr.length + red +
                           " | " + blue + "arr last element value = " + red + arr[arr.length-1] + reset);

        System.out.println("\nOf course, you don't need to run a loop to acquire the cyclic value\n"
                           + "you could just as well have used the 'mod' operator (%) to accomplish\n"
                           + "this value: -->" + blue + " int cyclicValue = n % 20; (" + reset + "a cyclic value of " 
                           + red + (n % 20) + reset + " is\nplaced into the cyclicValue variable)");

        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Just copy and paste it into a new Java Application project and run it.